# When I open the browser and enter my site it doesn't load the css on the first time, I have to reload the page to it to be loaded, why?

Tags: css

When I open the browser and enter my site it doesn't load the css on the first time, I have to reload the page to it to be loaded, why?

I just use this

```
<link href="<c:url value='/css/all.css'/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Using firebug I see I got an error http 302

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to change:
<link href="<c:url value='/css/all.css'/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
To:
<link href="css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the help, I tried this now, but still not working.